# How the Firebase Crashlytics tags such as Early crashes, repetitive crashes, regression issue, Fresh issue etc work?

Tags: firebase, crash, crashlytics, anr

What is the logic behind calculating the tags such as Early crashes,  repetitive crashes, regression issue, Fresh issue, etc which appear on crashlytics dashboard?
Is there any reference available as I am unable to find out any information in the documentation.
I need this information for filtering out my crashes and giving them priority.

Answer (score 1):

Regressed issues are documented in [what is a regressed issue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/troubleshooting?platform=ios#what-is-a-regressed-issue):

> An issue has had a regression when you've previously closed the issue but Crashlytics gets a new report that the issue has re-occurred. Crashlytics automatically re-opens these regressed issues so that you can address them as appropriate for your app.

Click the link for an example too.

Aside from that, the best I can find it this description in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#october_8_2021):

> You can now see Signals appearing in the Crashlytics console to indicate that certain issues have interesting characteristics that may be more important to your app health. We’re launching three Signals to start:
>
> - "Fresh issue" - new issues within the last week.
> - "Early crashes" - the majority of these crashes happened near app start.
> - "Repetitive crashes" - crashes your users are encountering over and over.

You can also find details about each of these signals in the Firebase console, when you hover over a crash of that specific type.